# Error in _Imports_razor.g.cs when trying to upgrade Blazor Server from .NET5 to .NET 6

Tags: blazor, migrate, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate my Blazor server app from .NET5 to .NET6 and I am getting the following error the moment I change the Target Framework to .NET6 in VS2022.

**The error:**

Error   CS0118  '__builder' is a variable but is used like a type
D:\Work\Wand\WandSite\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator_Imports_razor.g.cs

**_Imports.Razor**

```js
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using {ASSEMBLY NAME}
@using {ASSEMBLY NAME}.Shared
@using WandSite
@using WandSite.Shared
@using WandSite.Data
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@using WandSite.Classes
@using WandDal.Models
```

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Txzy.png)

Comment: Post your code and any errors as text in the question itself. Images can't be googled, compiled or tested. Post your `_Imports.razor` file.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post

Comment: `@using {ASSEMBLY NAME}` ? Is that the actual line in the file?

Comment: Yes it is, should I try to remove it ?

Comment: BTW, I had no problems migrating from 3.1 to 5 at the moment.

Comment: The only way that could happen is if you had a tool that replaced `{ASSEMBLY NAME}` with something else. Even if that was a valid preprocessor directive (it's not) it wouldn't be *two* words. Is your project using some custom build steps?

Comment: Remove these lines, you already have WandSite and WandSite.Shared. When you have source control (you should), look at the history for this file.

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right !!! finally I can use the Hot Reload capability.
I really appreciate your help...